# Javascript prototype and accessing parent object of 'this'

Tags: javascript, prototype, durandal

In Durandal, I'm working on a page that lists a number of doctors. Each row has a delete button. Here's my **View Model**:

```
var Doctor = function() {};

Doctor.Model = function(data) {
  this.id = data.id;
  this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

Doctor.prototype.activate = function() {
  this.doctorArr = ko.observableArray();

  // Start Doctor List
  this.load();
};

Doctor.prototype.load = function() {
  // load list into this.doctorArr()
}

Doctor.prototype.remove = function() {
  console.log(this);
};
```

And here's my **View**:

```
<button data-bind="click: remove">Remove Function</button>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: doctorArr }">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span> - <a data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Delete...</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on the `<button>` will return:

`Doctor {doctorArr: function, activate: function…}`

But clicking on the link inside the foreach function will return the model:

`Doctor.Model {id: "104", name: function}`

The problem is that I can't figure out how to access doctorArr from inside the remove function when 'this' returns the Model. I need it to remove the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the method `bind` to change the 'meaning' of this (the scope) inside the function you are calling. You have some options:

Add the `bind` to call the ViewModel within the desired scope:

```
<li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span> - <a data-bind="click: $parent.remove.bind($parent)">Delete...</a>
</li>
```

If you want to remove it without a method in the ViewModel. This will magically remove the item from the array:

```
<li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span> - <a data-bind="click: $parent.doctorArr.remove.bind($parent.doctorArr)">Delete...</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside your view model you aren't assigning what 'this' is, so each time you are calling remove it is passing in a different context.

```
var Doctor = function() {};

Doctor.Model = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = data.id;
  this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

Doctor.prototype.activate = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.doctorArr = ko.observableArray();

  // Start Doctor List
  this.load();
};

Doctor.prototype.load = function() {
  var self = this;
  // load list into this.doctorArr()
}

Doctor.prototype.remove = function() {
  var self = this;
  console.log(this);
};
```

Comment: Even if I assign `this` to `self`, it will still return the Model.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument knockout passes to your event bindings is the root model:

```
Doctor.prototype.remove = function(model) {
  console.log(model.doctorArr);
};
```